# Android Bitmap Out of Memory

Tags: android, memory-leaks, bitmap, out-of-memory

In my app I have 3 activities as tabs. All of them have 4 ImageView. I set background of these views by using setBackgroundDrawable method. I cant use layouts, because my bitmaps are dynamic, coming from internet. I checked size of bitmaps, they are normal, already i get error (Out Of Memory) after i click different tabs 3. time, no matter order.

I get the error just in hd phones, probably it is about scaling bitmaps to up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

the reason of the error is that I created the bitmaps in onCreate method and set them to background of views.

As a solution I create the bitmaps in onResume method, set backgrounddrawables and in onPause method I set bakground drawables to null.